# C++ Using a Class return function in another Class if statement

Tags: c++

Alright, I have been having this problem for a while and I believe I have pin-pointed where the problem is, but I am not sure how to fix it.

```
void Unit::AddStatusEffect(StatusEffect effect)
{
    // Add status effect and if it effects what actions a unit can do, do it here.
    myEffects.push_back(effect);

    if( effect.GetEffect == effect.STUN)
    {
        myCanMove = false;
        myCanAttack = false;
        myCanCast = false;
    }
    else if (effect.GetEffect == effect.MUTE)
    {
        myCanCast = false;
    }
    else if (effect.GetEffect == effect.BLIND)
    {
        myCanHit = false;
    }
    else
    {}


}
```

My problem seems to be with the effect.GetEffect return function within the StatusEffect class.  If I ask if(effect.STUN == effect.STUN) I get no errors which is why I believe the function is the problem. The error I get seems to be:

function call missing argument list; use '&StatusEffect::GetEffect' to create a pointer to member

(Here is the class in case there is something in there that may be the problem)

```
class StatusEffect
{
public:
    enum Effect { POISON, BURN, BLEED, FREEZE, MUTE, STUN, BLIND, ATKBOOST, HPREGEN, MANAREGEN, MATKBOOST, DEFENSEBOOST, MAGICDEFENSEBOOST };

private:
Effect myEffect;

public:
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Data Retrievers
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Effect const GetEffect() { return myEffect; }



StatusEffect(void);
~StatusEffect(void);
};
```

I hope I explained my problem well enough.  Everything I read up on didn't seem to help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In `Unit::AddStatusEffect`, replace `effect.GetEffect` by `effect.GetEffect()`

The difference between `effect.GetEffect` and `effect.GetEffect()` is that the first evaluates to a pointer to a member function (the function does not get called) while the second evaluates to the returned value of the function call.

Comment: @Uulamock Most of us have been through enough stupid mistakes. Don't feel bad. Glad I could help.

Comment: Yeah, I have had plenty of stupid mistakes, but I have always found them on my own.  So this is the first stupid mistake I didn't see. >.<

Answer (score 0):

You have to call a method or function by adding parentheses, even if there is no argument.

```
effect.GetEffect()
```